# URLSearchParams ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do a query to a view in my db and I would to use the URLSearchParams to complete the query's url.

I need to comunicate with CouchDB View, this is the reason why I should pass a startkey with some params

I have tried in this way:

```
 let _viewOption = {
        startkey: ['SENDER', values.name, values.surname]
    }
 var url = new URL(myUrlViewLink)
 let params = new URLSearchParams(_viewOption)
```

What I would to obtain is something like:

> `myUrlViewLink?startkey=['SENDER',values.name,values.surname]`

How can I do?

Comment: So what is the question here? Can't you just use regex?

Comment: the question is how to insert _viewOption values inside the query's url

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about encodeURI

```js
const name = "some name";
const surname = "some surname";

const uri = `http://example.com/?key=sender&name=${name}&surname=${surname}`


console.log(encodeURI(uri))
```

If you are using PHP as backend, you can get the value from `$_GET`, if you are using nodejs as backend you can use `req.query`

Comment: I need to comunicate with CouchDB View, this is the reason why I should pass a startkey with some params

Comment: specify in your question. how would anyone know what backend u r using.